# react-native app not displaying images in ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, image, react-native

**What could be causing the images not to display in the iOS simulator?**

I'm trying to display jpg images in an app build with react-native.
Unfortunatelly this is what I see in the simulator:

[image]

I've added the images under `Images.xcassets` folder like this and run `build` in xcode.

[image]

I also tried moving the Apple image out of the Fruit subfolder.

The code that should include the image looks like this:

```
<Image
    source={require('image!Apple')}
    style={styles.galleryItem}
/>
```

Style is defined like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    galleryItem: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 3,
        marginRight: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#000'
    }
});
```

**System**

- iojs: 1.6.1
- react-native: 0.8.0

Comment: try 'preloading' the files in the constructor part. e.g place this line require('image!Apple');  under constructor. also, make sure to launch a new packager.

Comment: Make sure you add the same image but for different screensizes (e.g. 2x, 3x etc).

Comment: @boredgames Thanks but this did not make any difference.

Comment: @AndyB Thanks for the hint. The problem was solved once I added images for all screen sizes. I previously had only one.